# Characters not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, utf-8, special-characters, iso-8859-1

This project is properly displaying characteres using `ISO-8859-1` (main page) on server and a Javascript `UTF-8`, however this function on server displays the string ("Observações") properly configured using UTF-8, however when I try to execute it locally it displays `Observações` as `ObservaÃ§Ãµes`.

My main page is set to `ISO-8859-1`:

```
<META content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

and it calls the script like this:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/functions.js"></SCRIPT>
```

what I don't understand is why it works on server but not on my computer and how to fix it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What if you set the main page's encoding to utf-8?

Comment: Please have a look at the duplicate, I'm pretty sure that's the same issue. If it isn't, please update your question with any new insights regarding HTTP headers.

Comment: If I set, the whole page displays triangles instead of special characters. And when using ISO-5589-1 it displays properly, but not the string inside javascript

Comment: Please be specific and update your question. "Set" what exactly where? What encoding is your JS file saved as to begin with?

Comment: When I say 'set' I mean the charset is set to `ISO-5589-1`. And my JS file is saved as `UTF-8 w/o BOM`

Comment: Seems like the file was corrupted somehow, after creating a new one and setting the enconding of the new JS file to UTF-8 it worked!